# Hibernate with MSSQL autoincrement column type. How to add a record

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, auto-increment

I have a column on MSSQL with autoincrement genertor in Id. Try to map it with Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[Request]")
public class Request implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @Column(name = "[Date]")
    java.sql.Timestamp date;
...
}
```

Add record method:

```
public static Request addRequest(Request r) throws IOException{
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx=null;

        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();  
            session.save(r);
            tx.commit();
            }
        catch (Exception e) {if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();e.printStackTrace();}
        finally {session.close();}
        return r;
    }
```

object that I'm trying to add:

```
request = new Request();           
Timestamp date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
request.setDate(date);
```

Object that I'm trying add to database:
Request{id=null, date=2017-12-12 09:24:11.721}

Error from database:
DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.

That is right but the id should generated automaticly becouse I used: strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This solve a issue:

org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect